# How can I select between different UV Maps?

Tags: uv, interface

I'm only trying to find the checkbox to active the UV map.

I know it must be simple, and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Go into the mesh data tab and select the UV map you wish to be active

Comment: @blendernoob If this answer helped you, please accept it by hitting that green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in the UV Editor (You will need to slide the edge of the window way over to see it).
[image]

Comment: I was wondering why you can't switch in the UV editor. Turns out you can ... :)