# Add an additional UV map to mesh

Tags: uv-image-editor

It should be possible to have multiple UV maps for one mesh, but I cannot figure out how. I cannot rename the default UVMap either. The given answer does not really seem to apply. For example, he sets the name manually but I cannot figure out how I should do that.

Comment: @Photon Yes it is, but I do not understand the answer. It just fiddles with textures, I do not get an option to change UV map name, for example. Also I am in Cylces if that matters

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45917/how-can-i-select-between-different-uv-maps. To rename UV map double click its name